# SpriteKit integrate in to UIKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, swift3

I want to create an app with lot of animations like games.

Which is the best method to add animations in iOS app? Is it possible to add SpriteKit animations in to UIKit app? , I would like to know is there any tutorials available.

Comment: Do You absolutely want to use SpriteKit, or do You need a way to draw animations and You are not picky about it?

Comment: Really I don't want to use sprite kit itself, actually I need tutorial screen that should not be a video, its an animation that shows him and take him step by  step to complete a full process. Which is the better way to do this?

Comment: For tutorial its more appropriate to use more scripted behavior as You said step by step. I have will add an answer with several libraries that can be used for animations.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for nice animations in iOS.

[Lotie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios), [Keyframes](https://github.com/facebookincubator/Keyframes) or a [Spritesheet solution](https://github.com/NachoSoto/NSBSpritesheetLayer).

EDIT : 
Lotie and Keyframes are similar libraries, they both work with After Effects ( I haven't used them personally, but I have seen some great animations done with them ). I used NSBSpritesheetLayer in two personal projects and it worked as expected. Here is some more info about spritesheets: [link](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099)

Comment: Thank you for giving libraries, let me check with requirements.

Comment: You should avoid link-only answers and include a relevant context which actually answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will edit my answer with some context about the libraries.